# d3.js draw line source and target is different (from an arc generated by d3.svg.arc() to the nodes with Cardinal position)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, automatic-ref-counting, line

I atttemp to add some text with rect inside the [sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426.)

For the `Sunburst` , the inner arc ring, the x,y represents angle and radius, However, the rect inside the `sunburst` is represented by `Cardinal position`.

For drawing lines, I know I can use d3.svg.line or d3.svg.diagonal. But their source and target are the same type.

But in my case the x,y in `source` and `target` is different.

How should I do?

I know I could change the inner rect to arc position, so that source and target can match.

But Is there a good way to do that?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Custom the source and target of d3.svg.diagonal().
Transform the source and target's space with different methods.

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                        .source(function (d) {
                            var innerRadius = Math.max(0, y(d.source.y));
                            var arcCenter = x(d.source.x + d.source.dx/2.0);

                            return {"x": innerRadius * Math.cos(Math.PI - arcCenter),      //radial space
                                "y": innerRadius * Math.sin(Math.PI - arcCenter)};
                        })
                        .target(function (d) {                                           //normal space
                            return {"x": d.target.y + rect_height / 2,
                                "y": d.source.x ? d.target.x : d.target.x + rect_width};
                        })
                        .projection(function (d) {
                            return [d.y, d.x];
                        });
```